# generic.Listview does not show in URL list in DRF Viewer

Tags: python, django

I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is.  When I go to the DRF Viewer, alerts is not listed in the possible list of urls. all the other Rest URLs do.

here's my serializer.py:

```
class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Options
        fields = '__all__'

        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Options.objects.all(),
                fields=('Member', 'skey', 'Time_Period')
            )
        ]
```

api.py:

```
class OptionViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OptionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the options
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return Options.objects.filter(Member=user)
```

and my urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', api.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', api.GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'currency', api.BitCoinViewSet)
router.register(r'latest_prices', api.CurrencyLatestViewSet)
router.register(r'options', api.OptionViewSet.as_view, 'alerts')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))

]
```

Why does the `alert` url not show up?  Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `as_view`, which you haven't used for any of the other routes? Or, if you *call* that method, as you usually would in a URLconf: `api.OptionViewSet.as_view()`?

Comment: if I remove `as_view`, i get a parameter error:  `TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.  when I put it back in, the error disappears.

Comment: And as I mention, what happens if you call that method?

Comment: if I specifically call that method (say like using restman), it gives me a URL 404 error

Comment: Simple `router.register(r'options', api.OptionViewSet, 'alerts')` should work right ?

Comment: We use, `.as_view()`  when you want to get only GET or POST or PUT or types , but not all the default methods

Comment: @rmerugu, sorry.  when I remove `.as_view()`, I get a parameter error:  `TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.  am I missing something elsewhere?

Comment: Just be sure here, you have tried using **api.OptionViewSet.as_view()** instead of **api.OptionViewSet.as_view()**, right?

Comment: sorry....that looks identical to me.  I'm confused.

Comment: bit I did try `as_view()` and `as_view`.  both didn't show up.

Comment: My bad, I did indeed mean with and without parentheses.

Comment: yeah, in both cases, the DefaultRouter did not show them on the viewer, nor did they become a registered URL in that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routers only work with `ViewSet`s, but your `OptionViewSet` is an ordinary `APIView`.

You should be able to fix it by just using the appropriate mixins and base class:

```
class OptionViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = OptionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the options
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return Options.objects.filter(Member=user)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you please elaborate?  can I make my OptionViewSet as a ViewSet so DefaultRouter and other stuff like DRF Docs will recognize it? if so, how?

Comment: @arcee123 sure, I've expanded my answer

Comment: guess I'm learning about mixins next.  Thanks much.  Let me get back to the server this afternoon and give this a shot.  Thanks much Daniel!